# Is this class structure method correct/desireblable? (MVC/C#)

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, class, business-objects

I'm building a MVC application which is a bit more complex than what I usually do and I want to try a new class structure. Basically theres a lot of reading going on. Just 5-10% of operations will be insert/update against the database.

Because of this, I'm thinking of creating base DTO classes which would be returned from a database layer. Then, business objects would inherit from the DTO class in order to extend the basic structure with all the validation and business rules.

Example:

```
namespace Project.DTO
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Surname;
        ...
    }
}

namespace Project
{
    public class Employee : Project.DTO.Employee
    {
        public bool IsValid()
        {
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a good approach? What I haven't thought off yet is how to use them inside the MVC, as the "correct" way would be to implement model classes. I believe I could create model classes that inherited from the DTO objects as well... but I'm unsure.

I would also need a way to handle all validation functions with some kind of Interface, as to avoid repeating to much generic code on the GUI.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use a completely different approach. My primary thoughts are these:

- I would like looser coupling between the classes, so I would not have my model classes inherit from my DTO objects
- I would probably not include validation logic in my model classes

This would lead to the following structure to start with:

```
namespace Project.DTO
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Surname;
        ...
    }
}

namespace Project
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When it comes to the validation logic, I would make an interface for the validation logic, that is injected into the `Emplyee` class:

```
public interface IValidator<T>
{
    bool IsValid(T objectToInspect);
}
public class Employee
{
    private readonly IValidator<Employee> validator;
    public Employee(IValidator<Employee> validator)
    {
        this.validator = validator;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public bool IsValid()
    {
        return validator.IsValid(this);
    }
}
```

This opens up your design for a whole range of features, including using IoC containers and better support for testing.

Comment: Intreseting, I am facing a similar problem. Your reply helped me a lot

Comment: The interface option is something I've done in the past and works well. But regarding loose coupling, the Business class will have at least the same properties of the DTO object, so by defining all of the fields two times I believe you are taking the long road.

Comment: @DaniH: it is not necessarily so that the business class has all the properties of the DTO. You may very well have business classes with fewer properties for certain uses, or perhaps even cases where one DTO splits up into several different business classes.

Comment: I ended up using this route. I ended up creating an EmployeeValidator class to validate the Employee object. I feel comfortable with this setup as the validation part is held separately, nice and tidy.

Inside the Employee class I just added an IsValid class that calls the validater, in very similar way as Fredrik posted.

Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

What if validation has to check with a rule whose parameters must come from database? Your entity would not have a knowledge and the way to access that parameter.

Creating Model/ViewModel is good but validation usually require more complex logic which would warrant dedicated classes - so I would not normally implement `IsValid` on my entity.

However, you can use `System.Component.DataAnnotation` validation attributes against simple properties of your entities.

Comment: What I have in mind is that the Employee class that inherits from the DTO is the one that has the validation routines, which would include checks against the DB if necesarry.

About the DataAnnotation, would they work if they are not in a class that inherits from the Controller class? I was also evaluating using a partial class for this...